# Web3 module undefined error while using javascript, solidity and html

Tags: javascript, html, solidity

I am trying to build UI for my solidity contract. So far the files are as follows:

```
index.html : which contains ui part(tables, buttons, etc)

    server.js:

        var express = require('express');
        var app = express();
        app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));
        app.listen(8080,() => console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!'));

    index.js:
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
    abi = JSON.parse('[{"constant":true,"inputs"......');
    // In your nodejs console, execute contractInstance.address to get the address at which the contract is deployed and change the line below to use your deployed address
    VotingContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
    contractInstance = VotingContract.at('deployed address name');
    //rest of the functions required..

Solidity file: this contains the contract that will deployed on the blockchain
```

When i run my server at localhost i get an error saying web3 is not defined.
can anyone help me with this??
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
I just had to include web3 in my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var Web3 = require('web3');
```